# Remove only one newline from the end of string in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a string like below

```
test1
test2
test3
newline
newline
newline
```

here i am using `s = s.TrimEnd(ControlChars.Cr, ControlChars.Lf)` to remove the last newline only, but it's removing all three newline.

i want to remove only one last newline from the string if any

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 5):

you can try like:

```
if (s.EndsWith(Environment.NewLine)) {
s = s.Remove(s.LastIndexOf(Environment.NewLine)) }
```

Comment: +1 For simplest straight forward working solution :)

Answer (score 0):

> Get last space and then get sub string.

```
Dim lastIndex = s.lastIndexOf(" ")
s = s.substring(0, lastIndex)
```

*(Or)*

> Use `split` function

```
Dim s = "test1 test2 test3 newline newline newline"
Dim mySplitResult = myString.split(" ")
Dim lastWord =  mySplitResult[mySplitResult.length-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

we can do as below

```
Dim stringText As String() = "test1 test2 test3 newline newline newline"

Dim linesSep As String() = {vbCrLf}
Dim lines As String() = stringText.Split(linesSep, StringSplitOptions.None)
If stringText.EndsWith(vbCrLf) Then
   Dim strList As New List(Of String)
   strList.AddRange(lines)
   strList.RemoveAt(lines.Length - 1)
   lines = strList.ToArray
End If
```

it worked for me!!!!

Answer (score -1):

Here you go.

```
s = s.substring(0, s.lastindexof(characterToBeRemoved))
```

Comment: -1 This will always remove the last existing endl. or break if there is no endl. I think he wants to remove the last endl. only when the string ends with and endl.

Comment: But he just wants to remove the last endl based on his given string, the idea on my answer is there. He'll be the one to add some conditions if he wanted to.

Comment: He actually had better code already that would do the same, without **breaking** in case of nonexisting newline, with the `.TrimEnd(...)` So though your argument aka. "he should implement it, i give him the hint" is valid in some cases on SO, it's not here since you gave the OP a **bad** hint.

Comment: would you mind if you tell me how it turned out to be **Bad** so that I can improve my answers on future questions? :)

Comment: Well your code only works in a specific case (when the last index of newl. also is the last character of the string). In other cases it does an undesired effect (removing any last newl.) or even worse causes an Exception if there are no newl. at all in the string. You need to account for the other cases.